# How do I use MAAS to create a Debian Image?

Tags: maas

How do I create a Debian image in MAAS?  All I found were some ubuntu releases and CentOS, is there any way to create a debian image ? if so how do I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is how you do it, for all those who are stuck just the way I was.

```
wget http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/openstack/8.7.1-20170215/debian-8.7.1-20170215-openstack-amd64.raw

maas login your.user http://<maasserver>:5240/MAAS 'user:credentials'
maas your.user boot-resources create name=custom/debian title="debian-8.7.1" architecture=amd64/generic content@=debian-8.7.1-20170215-openstack-amd64.raw
```

Comment: using http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/openstack/current-10/debian-10-openstack-amd64.raw   not download link

Comment: I'm using your answer to create an Debian image on u20.04 and MAAS but during the deploy I've this issue https://pasteboard.co/J8HifZ5.png

Answer (score 2):

More complete answer:

Download a debian cloud image in raw format.

Mount the image

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/loop
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 <nameofdebianimage.raw> /mnt/loop
```

Convert to a gzipped tarball

```
cd /mnt/loop
sudo tar czvf ~/debian.tgz .
sudo umount /mnt/loop
```

Upload this to maas

```
cd ~
maas login your.user http://<maasserver>:5240/MAAS 'user:credentials'
maas your.user boot-resources create name=custom/debian title="debian" architecture=amd64/generic content@=debian.tgz
```

Edit /etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata_custom and add the following at the top after the comment line and before debconf_selections to override the kernel to install:

```
kernel:
  fallback-package: linux-image-amd64
  package: linux-image-amd64
```

Comment: Ran into this issue after following those instructions https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1673655

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers and on my own research I've made a [short guide to make Debian 9 run on MaaS with the UEFI SecureBoot](https://github.com/juan-vg/maas/wiki/Create-a-Debian-9-(Stretch)-image-that-works-with-UEFI-secure-booting). There are [some changes to be made to the source code](https://github.com/juan-vg/maas/commit/6635951fa7c4f900de45fad28bd73591a2591280) as well in order to be able to complete the deploy successfully. I will summarize the contents in the following lines.

If you want to boot using UEFI and SecureBoot, the main step is to **include the buster debian repos** to the image so *curtin* will be able to install the packages *grub-efi-amd64-signed* and *shim-signed* (that are not present on stretch repos).

```
root@maas:~/custom-oses# mkdir /mnt/custom-os-loop
root@maas:~/custom-oses# mount -o rw,loop,offset=1048576,sync debian-9.7.0-openstack-amd64.raw /mnt/custom-os-loop
root@maas:~/custom-oses# chroot /mnt/custom-os-loop
root@maas:/# echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
root@maas:/# apt update
root@maas:/# exit
root@maas:~/custom-oses# umount /mnt/custom-os-loop
```

Don't worry about breaking the system, as cloud-init will replace the *sources.list* file on the first boot.

Beside this in order to not override the sources that the image contains, the behavior of MaaS must be changed. Inspecting the code you will see that it's not possible to modify the value of the cloud-init's directive *preserve_sources_list*, it's going to be *False* always. The solution is to modify the function *get_archive_config* in the file *compose_preseed.py*.

```
archives['apt']['preserve_sources_list'] = True if node.osystem == 'custom' else preserve_sources
```

At this point the Debian OS will be installed successfully, but it will not be able to boot automatically. MaaS doesn't support Debian, so when providing the EFI directives to boot there is something missing. Locate the file *config.local.amd64.template* under the *uefi* directory, and add the following lines under the ubuntu ones.

```
debian/shimx64.efi \
debian/grubx64.efi \
```

And that's it!

**Remember that if you edit the python files that are being run, you must remove the *pycache* and restart the services before seeing the changes**