# How to deploy a Debian Image for MAAS?

Tags: maas

I'm following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882911/how-do-i-use-maas-to-create-a-debian-image) but using all task when I try to run the deploy the issue is Kernel Panic. My lab is based on u20.04 an MAAS 2.7.0

[image]

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

to deploy custom images in MAAS you need to have a subscription from Canonical.
You can see here.
https://maas.io/docs/image-builder

And here:
https://ubuntu.com/pricing/infra

Comment: I've seen the first link but when I try to open it its feedback is https://pasteboard.co/J99gksL.png and I can't get the repository to install maas-image-builder

Comment: You don't see it because you need to pay a subscription to have access to that tool.

Comment: ok and how can I do that?

Comment: As you can see here https://maas.io/docs/images, you can subscribe for Ubuntu Advantage here: https://ubuntu.com/support?_ga=2.100668741.555644920.1590398430-1923963524.1564062242

Comment: but is it enough to get a essential plan?